# declare function pointer in templated class from template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, generic-programming

I am trying to declare function pointer from template argument of function prototype

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args> class DllFunction {
public:
  ReturnType (*fptr_)(Args...);
};

DllFunction<int(int)> f;
```

but I get this error:

> error: C2091: function returns function

Comment: `DllFunction<int, int> f;`?

Comment: You would need to use `DllFunction<int, int>`. `int(int)` is just one type parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing two different ways.

Or you declare `DllFunction` receiving the return and the variadic list of argument types

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args> class DllFunction {
public:
  ReturnType (*fptr_)(Args...);
};
```

but you have to avoid to call it with the form `int(int)` and you have to use

```
// .........VVV  return type
DllFunction<int, int> f;
// ..............^^^  arguments types
```

or you call using the form `ReturnType(Args...)` and you have to declare a `DllFunction` object as follows

```
template <typename>
class DllFunction;

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
class DllFunction<ReturnType(Args...)> {
public:
  ReturnType (*fptr_)(Args...);
};
```

You can also use the pointer function form

```
template <typename>
class DllFunction;

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
class DllFunction<ReturnType(*)(Args...)> {
public:
  ReturnType (*fptr_)(Args...);
};
```

so you can use `decltype()` for the template type

```
int foo (int);

DllFunction<decltype(&foo)> f;
```